# How can I use environment variables in a docker run command?

Tags: docker

If I pass an environment variable which is set inside of the container as an argument to `docker run`, my shell evaluates it. For example:

I want my container to print the value of `$FOO` which is `bar`. None of these will work:

```
# Prints blank line
$ docker run -e FOO=bar ubuntu echo $FOO

# Prints '$FOO'
$ docker run -r FOO=bar ubuntu echo \$FOO
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works if you run `echo` in a shell:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -e FOO=bar ubuntu bash -c 'echo $FOO'
bar
```

This is because `echo` is a command (`/bin/echo`), but it's the shell that does the variable substitution.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason; it's actually the host expanding the variable before it's sent to docker i.e. `FOO="bar" && docker run ubuntu echo $FOO` prints bar

Comment: The second part of the question escapes the variable as `\$FOO`, which prevents expansion and results in `$FOO` being printed.